# DataTable column visibility

Tags: javascript, datatables

My DataTable at the moment

```
<table id='table' class="display hover row-border">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="group1">Oranges</th>
      <th class="group1">Bananas</th>
      <th class="group1">Melons</th>
      <th class="group1">Tangerines</th>
      <th class="group1">Apple</th>
      <th class="group2">Cucumber</th>
      <th class="group2">Tomatoo</th>
      <th class="group2">Pepper</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

I have divided my columns into two categories and have placed them into the following divs.

```
<li>
<h5> Category 1</h5>
<div id="buttons-group1"></div>
</li>       

<li>
<h5> Category 2</h5>
<div id="buttons-group2"></div>
</li>
```

The issue I have is that I only seem to be able to control the default visibility of the columns in the category at the top, in this case category 1. Since I want only two out of five columns from category 1 to be shown when the page loads the second category seems to live a life on its own.

If I would move Category 2 above Category 1 I would be able to control category 2 but not 1 etc.

Any thoughts?

**Assigns the toggle buttons to the group divs:**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#test_table').DataTable();   

    var buttons1 = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'columnsToggle',
                columns: '.group1'
            }, 
        ]
    }).container().appendTo($('#buttons-group1'));

    var buttons2 = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'columnsToggle',
                columns: '.group2'
            }, 
        ]
    }).container().appendTo($('#buttons-group2'));
   });
```

**My current JavaScript in order to toggle buttons looks like this**

```
function DefaultButtons()
  {
    var table = document.querySelector('#table');
    var buttons = document.querySelector('.dt-buttons');
    var allButtons = buttons.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) 
    { 
      var button = allButtons[i]; 
      var name = button.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent; 
      if(name != 'Oranges' && name != 'Bananas')
      {
        console.log(name);
        button.click(); 
      }
    }
  }
```

**EDIT: ** Updated my code.

Comment: Can you post more of the html code? Your jquery selector is on something with `id="table"` and it's not clear what is going on there.

Comment: That would be my table, which has 10 columns. I then categorized these columns and their buttons into Group 1 and Group 2. I updated my code!

Comment: What I meant was we can see whats going on in the js but we have no idea what html the js is supposed to control because the html snippet doesn't give the full picture. column visibility, five columns etc, but where are all these things you talk about?

Comment: Sorry, added more information for you. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table')
```

means you want to get the element with the id="table".

It looks like both Tables have the same id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I updated my code. I only have one table, with 10 columns that I have categorized 5 of them as group1 and the other 5 as group2 in order to have the buttons in different colors for example.